# Convert string values in clomun to other string

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace, int

consider input df as:

```
name         value
abcd_1       dfgh
abcd_2       erty
abcd_3       yuio
abcd_4       uiop
abcd_5       yuio
abcd_6       yuio
abcd 7       tyui
abcd_8       tyui
abcd_9       ghjk
```

to  be converted as

```
name         value
a1       dfgh
a1       erty
a1       yuio
a2       uiop
a2       yuio
a2       yuio
a3       tyui
a3       tyui
a3       ghjk
```

What I want to happen here is in name column from abcd_1 to abcd_3 has to be replaced by a1 based on index(like abcd_1,2,3...) same ways for others.
Do not replace string manually but have to be done based on range like 1 to 3 of abcd with a1

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What's the rational? Every three rows get the same name?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: not for every three rows has to be done based on values after _ in abcd_number.

Comment: like for abcd_(range 1 to 3)- a1 abcd_(range 4 to 6)-a2

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Help your self with this example

```
    dict1 = {"abcd_1" : "ygfh", "abcd_2": "ghkj", "abcd_3": "whatever"}
    
    l1 = list(dict1.values()) 
    
    l2 = "a1", "a2", "a3" 
    
    
    final_dict = dict(zip(l2, l1)) 
    print(final_dict)
```

output

```
{'a1': 'ygfh', 'a2': 'ghkj', 'a3': 'whatever'}
```

Follow this approach, splitting the issue in small pieces leads you to fast result.

Comment: Generally, answers should be complete answers to solve the issue; unless caveated / acknowledged as partial answers.